# Corrections to self-energy/radius of an electron due to gravity

Tags: electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, electrons, coulombs-law, self-energy

I am currently reading Feynman's lectures on electromagnetism, and the question of the electrons self-energy, its size, and "what keeps it together" are mentioned in several places.

Now I want to clarify that my interest in physics is purely of a hobbyist, so my post here is just to help me clarify some things as best as I can with my current state of knowledge - mostly about what is the motive behind trying to calculate the self-energy of the electron, and why do we consider the results we obtain with classical theories incorrect.

Anyway, after reading a relevant topic here([Flaw in the radius of a spherical electron model (classical electron radius)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129682/flaw-in-the-radius-of-a-spherical-electron-model-classical-electron-radius)), it seems that the problems with this whole picture are :

1. It is "too big" - it would have be smaller than 10^-22 to not simply be ruled out by experiment.
2. If we accept that this self-energy comes from (hypothetical) bits of the electron repelling each other, this raises the question of what actually holds the electron together.
3. The scales are so small, we don't even have a reason to assume classical theories work there anyway.

In other words, if we assumed that the electron had a size smaller than 10^-22, its self-energy(and thus mass) would be much larger than 0.5MeV, and the question of what keeps those bits together still remains.

So my question is : would there be any chance that gravity compensates for those? Self-energy due to the "electron bits" attracting each other would be negative, cancelling out part of the electrostatic self-energy, and would also answer how are those bits kept together.

Obviously the problem here would be that gravity is much weaker than electric forces, so no matter how close we "push" the electron bits together, it wouldn't be enough to cancel out the electric self-energy - gravitational self-energy would increase, but so would electrostatic self-energy, and in fact, the total self-energy would increase.

So my actual question is : Could this be somehow addressed by taking account the non-linearity of gravity? Now GR is really out of my reach for the moment, however I have read that the strength of the gravitational field is dependent on the energy-content of the body or system or bodies. That is, if start with 2 positive(or negative) charges 1m apart and I push them together closer, the gravitational pull this 2-body system exerts into a distant 3rd body(let's say 1km away) will increase, due to the fact that I added energy to the system. By the same token, i assume that the gravitational self-energy of this 2-body system will increase, not only because of reduced distance, but also because of increased energy.

Is it possible then to get a radius smaller than 10^-22 with those corrections? My thinking is(forgive me for the very sloppy way of phrasing here) : if we imagine that we keep pushing the repelling bits together, the electrostatic self-energy increases, and with it, the mass. Since the mass/energy of the system increases, so does it gravitational self-energy, and actually faster than the electrostatic self-energy(but with a negative sign). At some point, there should be a threshold where gravity "balances out" the electrostatic forces, enough to give the actual mass of the electron(and also keep the bits together) :

As I said, GR is way off my abilities right now - all I could do is basically this, as a very silly first approximatoin :

Electrostatic self-energy, if we assume electron a finite charged sphere :

$$U = \frac{3Q^2}{5r_e}$$

Mass based on electrostatic energy:

$$m = \frac{U}{c^2}$$

Gravitational self-energy of the electron-sphere, if we plug in the mass calculated above:

$$Ug = \frac{3\frac{U}{c^2}^2}{5r_e} = \frac{3\frac{\frac{3Q^2}{5r_e}}{c^2}^2}{5r_e}$$

Now if I solve for U - Ug = 0.5MeV, I get re ~ 1.37 * 10^-36.

Now obviously the above are the scribblings of someone that has no idea how to deal with GR and non-linear gravity in general, but my question is : If we do take into account non-linear gravity, could we arrive at a similar result(with much more correct calculations of course?). Does the fact that we get a size that is even smaller than planck length means that the result is meaningless anyway? Or is the whole thinking(that negative gravitational self-energy could provide the corrections we need) wrong to begin with?

Comment: In modern physics the electron is considered a point particle. It has no physical extent, so trying to incorporate gravity to account for a physical extent is (in my opinion) outside the scope of this forum. Voting to close.

Comment: @hft : I understand that, but it's not like the issues I mentioned(self-energy, "what holds it together", size, etc) are something I invented. Feynman mentioned them in his lectures, for example https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_01.html#Ch1-S1, https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_28.html. What makes this question invalid?

Comment: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4538/

Comment: So Feynman lectures do not constitute mainstream physics? I believe I am simply asking a question about an already accepted framework. Classical electron radius is a thing, I'm simply asking what would we get if we derived it when also considering gravity.

Comment: Bongos have nothing to do with physics, i believe the classical electron radius does. I am simply asking what would change if we derived it when also considering gravity, and if would that tell us anything at all. I really don't understand this attitude.

Comment: In any case : as I said, all of those concepts are truly above my abilities - I was simply reading the lectures, and trying to make sense about the motivation for calculating things like self-energy or electron size to begin with, why gravity is not considered in that calculation etc. I was under the impression, since the lectures are not *ancient*, that they're still relevant, but if my question is truly nonsensical or enter quack-territory, fell free to close. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138611/discussion-between-hft-and-michael-mitsopoulos).

Answer (score 2):

Non-linearities in the gravitational field are generally negligible when the mass/energy $M$ contained in a region of size $R$ satisfies $GM/Rc^2 \ll 1$.  In this case, if we take $M$ to be the electron mass and $R \approx 10^{-36}$ m to be the radius you calculated, we get
$$
\frac{G M}{R c^2} \sim 10^{-21}.
$$
So at the level of classical GR, it is implausible that non-linearities in the gravitational field would significantly affect your result.